# Multiverse separate inventory per worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend has a Minecraft server, there is a survival world and a creative world made using multiverse. The problem is when a player goes into creative they can get diamonds, then leave and go to survival. Is it possible to make a separate inventory per world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you install the plugin [multiverse-inventories](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-inventories/)! Multiverse-inventories is a extension for multiverse to configure seperate inventories. If you installed it, you have to configure it.

How you are able to configure it you find in the *config.yml* as a comment. After you finished the configuration you have to reload the file with the command */mvinv reload*.

If you have any problems while installing or configurating take a look at the [offical wiki of mulitverse-inventories](https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Inventories/wiki).